# Get innertHTML of element from another page pureJS

Tags: javascript, html

I want get innerHTML of element from another page. I know solution of this problem with jQuery(with $load) but i want use pure Javascript.
Example code snippet;

```js
text = another element innerHTML from another page;
document.getElementsByClassName('show').innerHTML = text;
//pure JS codes will here
```

```html
<div class="show"></div>
```

Comment: Selectors are supported in Vanilla JS: `document.querySelector('.show').innerHTML`. querySelector only applies to first element. querySelectorAll would return a nodeList.

Comment: i don't want get text variable, i want get innerHTML of element which placed on another page. Such example; one box on index and another box on portal and i insert innerHTML of portal box to innerHTML to index box.

Comment: So if you want mimick `$load` why not taking a look at its [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/load.js) first? Then you can write plain JS similar way w/o deps on jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly to how jQuery's `load` fetches a page and inserts the text into an element, you can use the built-in `fetch` API to fetch an external page's text, use `DOMParser` to select the element you want from the response, and insert it into the DOM. For example:

```
fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then((responseText) => {
    const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(responseText, 'text/html');
    const elm = doc.querySelector('.foo');
    container.textContent = elm.textContent;
  });
```

```js
const responseText = '<div class="foo">foo content</div>';
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(responseText, 'text/html');
const elm = doc.querySelector('.foo');
container.textContent = elm.textContent;
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Also note that

```
document.getElementsByClassName('show').innerHTML = text;
```

won't work because `getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`, not a single element. Instead, use `querySelector` when you want to select the first element that matches a selector string.

Comment: thanks for help but i'm beginner javascript user and i can't understand where i place my url or how i get element on another page.

Comment: That's what the `fetch(url)` is - just replace that with your URL. The `doc.querySelector('.foo');` selects the element on the other page which has a class name of `foo` - just replace that with whatever selector string you want.

Comment: i use following code but not working for me
```show = document.getElementsByClassName("pm_show")[0];
fetch(http://localhost/mybb/private.php)
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then((responseText) => {
    const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(responseText, 'text/html');
    const elm = doc.querySelector('.pm_source');
    show.textContent = elm.textContent;
  });
});```

Comment: Strings need delimiters. That code will throw a syntax error - put the URL string in delimiters instead

Comment: okay i add " ' " and it's solved one more question; how i get all elements have .foo class name on another page?

Comment: Use `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector` to get a `NodeList` of all matching elements, and then you can iterate through them and do whatever you want with it

Comment: i use Array.from and it's fixed. Thanks for everything lot!

Answer (score 0):

re:  document.getElementsByClassName('show').innerHTML = text;

In your case, you may want to use

document.getElementsByClassName('show')[0].innerHTML = text;

to make it work.

As for getting the document, as per @CertainPerformance answer, use fetch in ES6, or XMLHttpRequest in earlier versions.